# Batch extract the highest number from a list of integers saved to file

Tags: arrays, batch-file, integer, max

I'm trying to extract the highest number from a list of integers saved to a file.

Example of the text file I read:

```
10
52
20
```

I can loop through the elements and find the correct result, but I'm having trouble saving it outside the loop. I don't have much experience with batch files, I just understand that it's a variable scope problem, but I don't understand how to fix it.

The batch in question is called from another batch, which contains the following commands:

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
setlocal EnableExtensions
call script.bat
```

**script.bat**

```
set "max_value=0"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "MaxNumber=0"
for /f "delims=" %%V in (%output_txt%) do (
    if not "%%V"=="" (
        for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%N in ("%%V") do if %%N GTR !MaxNumber! set "MaxNumber=%%N"
    )
)
echo Biggest number is: %MaxNumber%
set max_value=%MaxNumber%
endlocal
echo Biggest number is: %max_value%
```

Output obtained from the example:

> Biggest number is: 145
>
> Biggest number is: 0

I've seen several questions regarding the scope issue in similar situations, but I can't resolve or figure out where the error is?

Comment: If your numbers are the same number of digits, as in your example: ```@sort /r "%output_txt%" /o "tmp.txt"```; ```@set /p "max_value=" 0<"tmp.txt```; ```@echo Biggest number is: %max_value%```, ```@del "tmp.txt"```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setlocal` makes a copy of the current environment and processing continues using that new environment. An `endlocal` statement disposes of the new environment and restores the original (reaching physical end-of-file is an implicit `endlocal`.) When the original environment is restored, any changes made to it are backed out as though they had never happened so any value that is required beyond the `setlocal/endlocal` bracket needs to be preserved. You *can* write those values to a file and then read them back again after the `endlocal`, or use a parsing trick.

Batch first *parses* the line to validate it, then executes the parsed version. If the `endlocal` line is structured like this:

```
endlocal&set "var=%var%"
```

which may seem illogical, but the parser changes it to, and `cmd` executes it as

```
endlocal&set "var=thecurrentcontentsofvar"
```

"moving" the variable across the "`endlocal barrier`".

Answer (score 0):

You could, of course, get PowerShell to help you with this.

Here's an example line for your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) to get you on your way:

```bash
For /F %%G In ('powershell -NoP "(GC '%output_txt%' | Measure -Max).Maximum"') Do Echo Biggest number is: %%G
```

You could of course do it the less lazy way:

```bash
For /F %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Content -Path '%output_txt%' | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum"') Do Echo Biggest number is: %%G
```